# Flink complains Sort on a non-time-attribute field is not supported when group by proctime

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Flink 1.12,

I write a simple flink code as follows, it reads Stock record from StockSource, each Stock consists of three fields: `id,trade_date,price`. pt is the proctime.

When I run the sql as follows, flink complains that  Sort on a non-time-attribute field is not supported. I would like to know where the problem is.

The sql is:

```
    val sql =
    """
      select  pt, sum(price) from sourceTable
      group by  pt
      order by pt


      """.stripMargin(' ')

    tenv.sqlQuery(sql).toRetractStream[Row].print()
```

The flink code is:

```
object OrderByProctime {
  
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
    env.setParallelism(1)
    val ds: DataStream[Stock] = env.addSource(new StockSource())
    val tenv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
    tenv.createTemporaryView("sourceTable", ds, $"id", $"price", $"pt".proctime())

    //ERROR：
    //Sort on a non-time-attribute field is not supported. org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Sort on a non-time-attribute field is not supported.
    val sql =
    """
      select  pt, sum(price) from sourceTable
      group by  pt
      order by pt


      """.stripMargin(' ')

    tenv.sqlQuery(sql).toRetractStream[Row].print()

    env.execute()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flink SQL restricts temporal operations that can garbage collect materialized view state to tables that have a so-called *time attribute*. This is a timestamp field that is guaranteed to be (at least roughly) in-order -- so it must either be an event-time column that has watermarking defined on it (specifying the degree to which it can be out-of-order), or it must a processing-time column.

You are using an older version of Flink that I'm less familiar with, but I believe you should modify your `Stock` type to not have the `pt` field, and  then introduce the `pt` field as an additional field during the conversion to a Table. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/streaming/time_attributes.html#during-datastream-to-table-conversion-1. (Or you can keep the `pt` field as is, and add another column to be used as the time attribute during the conversion.)

Note that it's a bit inconsistent that you are specifying    `TimeCharacteristic.EventTime` in combination with trying to use processing time -- but I don't believe this is actually a problem. The whole time characteristic mechanism was deprecated in Flink 1.12, and no longer does anything.

Comment: Thanks @david-anderson for the helpful answer. `pt` field is not part of `Stock` case class, but it is an additional field using expression: `$pt.proctime()` as you have shown in the flink doc link. I think I need to upgrade my flink version to a newer one.